# ZF2 how to simulate ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, http-headers, zend-framework2

I have written a CMS with ZF2 and i am in the process of adding ajax capability to the system.

All my urls are normal so if JavaScript is disabled or there is a error in js code the links and form submissions can work normally , so far so good ...

I have a special layout for ajax and in modules `onDispach` event :

```
        if ($e->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest())
            $controller->layout('layout/ajax_layout_admin.phtml');
        else
            $controller->layout('layout/layout.phtml');
```

for normal links and forms without `file input` this works just fine.

And for forms with `file input` i just highjack the submit event and set the forms target to a iframe witch works as expected BUT ...

here comes the problem : in most of the actions for form submissions there is a redirect command. for example submit to new/edit action and redirect to list action, this works fine with ajax requests the page gets redirected with the correct header so the new action knows that this is ajax and sets the correct layout, BUT when using iframe the redirected action is loaded with the normal layout.

I tried setting the header my self before redirect but didn't make any difference.
I have a `BaseAbstractActionController` class and all my controllers extend this class so in this class :

```
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $this->_setViewModel();
    /* @var $request \Zend\Http\Request */
    $request = $e->getRequest();


    $layout = $this->params()->fromPost('systemLayout', false);
    if ($layout) {
        $this->layout('layout/' . $layout);
        //--------------------------------------- Trying to get this part to work
        if ($layout == 'form_submit') {
            $x = $this->request->getHeaders()->get('X_REQUESTED_WITH');
            if ($x)
                $this->request->getHeaders()->removeHeader($x);

            // ---------------------------------- didn't work
            $this->request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
                'X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
            ));

            // ---------------------------------- didn't work
            $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
                'X_REQUESTED_WITH' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
            ));
        }
    }

    return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```

so any solution for this problem ?

maybe setting a custom header before form is submitted with js ??? or ...

***PS: i can but prefer not to add extra params to the  redirect command, there is too many of them.***

Comment: Using iframe with ajax request is subject to Same-Origin Policy. You may want to dig about that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @foozy i am not using iframe with ajax and even if i did it has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: If the issue is not fixed yet then can you please provide us some sample code of the process (form, submit-handler, etc. from the view file). The view file is important here, not the controller.